# Django admin site: implement a singleton for global variables?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

Does anyone have experience (Django 1.x pref 1.3) with implementing a sort of singleton accessible from the admin page to expose some global variables for editing (site name, keywords, ...).
I cant find anything like this and it sounds quite unbelievable!

thanks

(django-preferences is broken with 1.x)

Comment: There is the mantra among the Django community that "the admin is not your app".  You may want to take that into consideration.

Comment: If I get your question right you're probably looking for something like this https://code.google.com/p/django-values/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lazerscience says, you probably want Django-dbsettings. I have a [fork at Github](http://github.com/danielroseman/django-dbsettings) that works with the latest Django versions.

Answer (score 0):

after some playing I had dbsettings working... but with a few glitches:
- Aptana doesnt recognise the import preferences as a valid reference
- when I access my /settings/ page with the fields of the model I created and then save it I have a `CSRF token missing or incorrect.` error

NOTE: The official googlecode repository doesnt work (with 1.3), Daniel's version does instead (I guess he changed newforms -> forms etc). The way I created a new model for the settings veiw is:

```
from django.db import models
import dbsettings

class ImageLimits(dbsettings.Group):
        maximum_width = dbsettings.PositiveIntegerValue()
        maximum_height = dbsettings.PositiveIntegerValue()
options = ImageLimits()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using singleton's as much as possible.

[Are Singletons really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020312/are-singletons-really-that-bad)

[What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

For the rest, site name is editable in Django admin (see django.contrib.sites module).

Talking about keywords - it's bad to repeat them, thus, you better implement it in your item model (page, news article, etc).

Could you maybe give more examples of what do you need it for?