# How to update QWindow in qt c++, text doesn't show

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm writing QT deskop app and I have a small issue.
I want to open new tab with text that I put from a file.

I have two class one in mainwindow.h and second in form.h

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void on_open_file_clicked();

    void on_search_keyword_clicked();

    void on_search_tag_clicked();

    void on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index);

    void show_tab(QString keywords);
    QString return_text();
public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_actionOpen_file_triggered();
    void on_actionShow_text_file_triggered();
    QVector<QString>find_logs_keywords(QString keywords);
private:
    QString  text = "example text";
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**form.h**

```
    #ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form();

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void text_to_plain(QString& text);

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
    #include <QFileDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDir>
#include <QVector>
#include <QStringList>
#include <iostream>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "search_keyword.h"
#include "search_tag.h"
#include "form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_open_file_clicked()
{
    QString filter = "log file (*log) ;; Tex File (*.txt)";
    QString file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file", QDir::homePath(), filter);
    QMessageBox::information(this,"..",file_name);
    QFile file(file_name);


    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) QMessageBox::warning(this,"title","file not open");
    else
    {
    QTextStream in(&file);
    text = in.readAll();
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
    ui->lineEdit->setPlaceholderText(file_name);
    }

    file.close();

}

void MainWindow::on_actionShow_text_file_triggered()
{
    show_tab("all logs");
    Form Fr;
    Fr.text_to_plain(text);
}

void MainWindow::show_tab(QString keywords)
{
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new Form(), QString("%1").arg(keywords));
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);
}
```

**form.cpp**

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form::text_to_plain(QString& text)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
}
```

My problem is after call method void MainWindow::on_actionShow_text_file_triggered() plain text in QWidget in Form is still empty i tried: this->update, this->repaint, Form::update(); Form::repaint(), QWidget::repaint(); QWidget::update();. Everything fail.

Comment: When you say everything fail, what happens. Please elaborate. Can you share the steps you tried. Can you share the compiler / runtime error. What platform are you running this. Linux / Mac / Windows ?  Welcome to stackoverflow !

Comment: By fail I mean it's not working. Nothing happend, QWidget is empty, text do not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your Form exists only in this function scope.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionShow_text_file_triggered()
{
    show_tab("all logs");
    Form Fr;
    Fr.text_to_plain(text);
}
```

Here -> `Form Fr;` the Form is created: constructor(`explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);`) of the class Form is called

And at this place -> `}` your Form is deleted: destructor(`~Form();`) of class Form is called. 
This happens because you create your Form instance on the function stack. So Fr is local object and exist only in the scope of the function `on_actionShow_text_file_triggered()` after the function is executed/finished all local variables are freed/destructed.

if your `Fr` object should exist not just in this function you need to create it on the heap instead of stack. 
P.S.: for case study read about stack vs heap for example hear: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Your `on_actionShow_text_file_triggered` function should then look like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionShow_text_file_triggered()
{
    show_tab("all logs");
    Form * Fr = new Form(this); //if you set parent object your Form will be automatically deleted/destructed then MainWindow is deleted/destructed
    Fr->text_to_plain(text);
    Fr->show(); // you should call show() function of QWidget class and subclasses to get your widget visible
}
```

Comment: I a little bit change you answer like that:
`void MainWindow::on_actionShow_text_file_triggered()
{
    Form *Fr = new Form(this);
    Fr->text_to_plain(text);
    show_tab("all logs", Fr);
}`

and:

`void MainWindow::show_tab(QString keywords, Form *f)
{
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(f, QString("%1").arg(keywords));
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);
}`

because widget did not show propertly.

Answer (score 0):

This `Form * Fr = new Form(this);` will create new form pointer every time. Would not it be better to create one global pointer to the form, call the functions and delete it later?

Comment: Why not? Take a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151074/13532465](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151074/13532465)