# Why do these secondary threads not end their execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm creating a console application that should receive messages from the network in order to process them. First I created a singleton class to ensure that the same queue is accessible by all classes: this class is `ProcessingQueue`.

```
public class ProcessingQueue
{
    public class ItemToProcess
    {
        public string SourceClientId { get; set; }
        public IMessage ReceivedMessage { get; set; }
    }

    private int m_MaxSize = 20;
    private Queue<ItemToProcess> m_InternalQueue;

    private static volatile ProcessingQueue m_Instance = null;
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    private ProcessingQueue()
    {
        m_InternalQueue = new Queue<ItemToProcess>();
    }

    public static ProcessingQueue Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (m_Instance == null)
                    {
                        m_Instance = new ProcessingQueue();
                    }
                }
            }
            return m_Instance;
        }
    }

    public int MaxSize
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                return m_MaxSize;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    m_MaxSize = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(String source, IMessage message)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            while (m_InternalQueue.Count >= m_MaxSize)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(syncRoot);
            }
            m_InternalQueue.Enqueue(new ItemToProcess { SourceClientId = source, ReceivedMessage = message });
            if (m_InternalQueue.Count == 1)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(syncRoot);
            }
        }
    }

    public ItemToProcess Dequeue()
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            while (m_InternalQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(syncRoot);
            }
            ItemToProcess item = m_InternalQueue.Dequeue();
            if (m_InternalQueue.Count == m_MaxSize - 1)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(syncRoot);
            }
            return item;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                return m_InternalQueue.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I implemented the main class of the project as follows.

1. First of all, the shared queue is instantiated.
2. Then I set a timer to simulate the arrival of a keep alive message (first producer).
3. Then I created the consumer thread (`processing` object).
4. Then I created another producer thread (`generating` object).
5. Finally, I run all the threads and the timer.

   class Program
   {
       static ProcessingQueue queue = ProcessingQueue.Instance;
       static System.Timers.Timer keep_alive_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

   ```
   private static volatile bool running = true;


   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       queue.MaxSize = 30;
       keep_alive_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
       {
           KeepAliveMessage msg = new KeepAliveMessage(Guid.NewGuid());
           Console.WriteLine("Keep Alive: " + msg.MsgId);
           queue.Enqueue("", msg);
       });
       keep_alive_timer.Enabled = true;
       keep_alive_timer.AutoReset = true;

       Thread processing = new Thread(delegate()
       {
           while (running)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Number of elements in queue: {0}", queue.Count);

               ProcessingQueue.ItemToProcess msg = queue.Dequeue();
               Console.WriteLine("Processed: msgid={0}, source={1};", msg.ReceivedMessage.MsgId, msg.SourceClientId);

               Thread.Sleep(1500);
           }
       });

       Thread generating = new Thread(MessagesFromNetwork);

       processing.Start();
       keep_alive_timer.Start();
       generating.Start();

       Console.WriteLine("RUNNING...\n");
       Console.ReadLine();

       running = false;
       keep_alive_timer.Stop();
       Console.WriteLine("CLOSING...\n");

       //processing.Abort();
       //generating.Abort();

       bool b1 = processing.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
       bool b2 = generating.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

       Console.WriteLine("b1 {0}", b1);
       Console.WriteLine("b2 {0}", b2);
       Console.WriteLine("END");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   static void MessagesFromNetwork()
   {
       string[] sourceClients = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
       while (running)
       {
           IMessage msg; // interface IMessage
           Random random = new Random();
           int type = random.Next(2);
           switch (type)
           {
               case 0:
                   msg = new KeepAliveMessage(Guid.NewGuid());   // implements IMessage
                   break;
               case 1:
                   msg = new TaskMessage(Guid.NewGuid(), ...);   // implements IMessage
                   break;
               default:
                   throw new Exception("Messaggio non valido!");
           }
           Console.WriteLine("New message received: " + msg.MsgId);
           queue.Enqueue(sourceClients[random.Next(sourceClients.Length)], msg);
           Console.WriteLine("... message enqueued: " + msg.MsgId);
           Thread.Sleep(500);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Pressing *Enter* during the execution, the `running` variable becomes false and both the thread should terminate. However this does not always happen, in fact one of the two methods `Join` did not return the control: for this reason I specified a timeout within the `Join` methods, but after `Console.WriteLine("END");` the console application freezes (the second `Join` returns `false`).

Maybe the second thread is not terminated properly ... Why?

Comment: Singleton is much easier to achieve with `Lazy<T>`, but I always thought Singleton is the crudiest of patterns. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1020384/14357

Comment: Ok, but I need a queue accessible to instances of a WCF service: in my code I simulate data from the network, but in reality many instances of a WCF service must put data in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Dequeue or Enqueue  could go into a `Monitor.Wait()` , when running is stopped nobody is pulsed.

You wait 5 seconds but note that MaxSize * 1500 > 5000

I couldn't so directly find out the Timer frequency.

Comment: Could I just change the wait time in the `Join` method? Or should I also use a simpler method instead of a `Monitor`?

Comment: Your Enqueue / Dequeue methods have no stopping logic at all... Just use a library class.

Comment: What do you mean by library class? Should I use a class as `ConcurrentQueue`?