# Industrial-strength n-ton base class template

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++11, singleton

I am working on an n-ton base class template. I don't worry about laziness yet, so the *Intent* is:

> Ensure a class has only n instances, and provide a global point of access to them.

Here is my code so far:

```
template<typename Derived, size_t n = 1>
class n_ton_base                 // Singletons are the default
{
    static Derived instances[n + (n == 0)];
                              // Zerotons are supported, too
protected:

    // Prevent n_ton_base to be used outside of inheritance hierarchies
    n_ton_base() {} 

    // Prevent n_ton_base (and Derived classes) from being copied
    n_ton_base(const n_ton_base&) = delete;

public:
                   // Get first element by default, useful for Singletons
    template<size_t i = 0>
    static Derived& get_instance()
    {
        static_assert(i < n, "Time to increase n it seems!");
        return instances[i];
    }
};
```

And here is how one would use it:

```
class SingletonExample : public n_ton_base<SingletonExample>
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << "Singletons are overused.\n";
    }    
};

class DoubletonExample : public n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2>
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << "Doubleton " << this << " says hello.\n";
    }    
};

int main()
{
    SingletonExample::get_instance().method();
    DoubletonExample::get_instance().method();
    DoubletonExample::get_instance<0>().method();
    DoubletonExample::get_instance<1>().method();
}
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't compile yet:

```
/tmp/ccsFtliS.o: In function `SingletonExample& n_ton_base<SingletonExample, 1ul>::get_instance<0ul>()':
nton.cpp:(.text._ZN10n_ton_baseI16SingletonExampleLm1EE12get_instanceILm0EEERS0_v[SingletonExample& n_ton_base<SingletonExample, 1ul>::get_instance<0ul>()]+0x5): undefined reference to `n_ton_base<SingletonExample, 1ul>::instances'
/tmp/ccsFtliS.o: In function `DoubletonExample& n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2ul>::get_instance<0ul>()':
nton.cpp:(.text._ZN10n_ton_baseI16DoubletonExampleLm2EE12get_instanceILm0EEERS0_v[DoubletonExample& n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2ul>::get_instance<0ul>()]+0x5): undefined reference to `n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2ul>::instances'
/tmp/ccsFtliS.o: In function `DoubletonExample& n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2ul>::get_instance<1ul>()':
nton.cpp:(.text._ZN10n_ton_baseI16DoubletonExampleLm2EE12get_instanceILm1EEERS0_v[DoubletonExample& n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2ul>::get_instance<1ul>()]+0x5): undefined reference to `n_ton_base<DoubletonExample, 2ul>::instances'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: n_ton_base::instances is static, so you should define it somewhere. At the moment you are only declaring it

Comment: You haven't added a definition for the static array?

Comment: I vote for this as douchey design pattern of the year.

Comment: It does compile actually, this is a linker error revealing a missing symbol.

Comment: I think it would be easier to create the static array n_instances in the function get_instance() rather than to declare it as a static member. See the C++ example of the "multiton pattern" on wikipedia.

Comment: "Industrial-strength" sounds a bit BS (although I do understand what you mean, this phrase is mostly found in commercials).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Etienne Cordonnier pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662673/industrial-strength-n-ton-base-class-template#comment20492756_14662673), it is much easier to use a local static instead of a class static:

```
template<typename Derived, size_t n = 1>
class n_ton_base                 // Singletons are the default
{
protected:

    // Prevent n_ton_base to be used outside of inheritance hierarchies
    n_ton_base() {} 

    // Prevent n_ton_base (and Derived classes) from being copied
    n_ton_base(const n_ton_base&) = delete;

public:
                   // Get first element by default, useful for Singletons
    template<size_t i = 0>
    static Derived& get_instance()
    {
        static_assert(i < n, "Time to increase n it seems!");

        static Derived instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Note that each instantiated member function will have its own local static, so no array is needed.

This also achieves [thread-safe lazy initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/) without me having to do anything about it. Nice!

Answer (score 8):

Add this at global scope:

```
template<typename Derived, size_t n>
Derived n_ton_base<Derived, n>::instances[n + (n == 0)];
```

Btw, `std::array<>` allows zero-size arrays, so you might want to consider it.

Comment: Interesting that you edited the `= 1` part away, how is that relevant?

Comment: @FredOverflow Default arguments are only allowed in the declaration or in the initial definition.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I removed it because default arguments cannot be overridden in a definition (and that's a definition). It works the same as with functions with default arguments: you can't add them both to the declaration and to the definition of a function, even though they are consistently specified. Initially I copy pasted the template argument list and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @David: We have to do this exactly because it is consider a declaration inside the class, and not a definition. Thus, we need to add a definition.

Comment: How does `std::array` allow zero-size arrays? A similar hack, or partial specialization?

Comment: @FredOverflow: pardon, fixed the typo. The way this is done is implementation-defined, I guess. The standard only specifies that 0 is a valid size. But yes, most likely they all use a similar hack. libstdc++ uses `instances[n ? n : 1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can find [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr038.htm) an explanation about class static members:

> Static data members (C++ only):
>
> The declaration of a static data member in the member list of a class is not a definition. You must define the static member outside of the class declaration, in namespace scope. For example:
>
> ```
> class X {
> public:
>     static int i;
> };
>
> int X::i = 0; // definition outside class declaration
> ```

Therefore you have to define `n_ton::instances` outside of your class.